# Need to use an array in nimblekit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sencha-touch

I am using nimblekit sencha and xcode for developing an app, In Xcode a fill a tableview with items from an array, that array was filled from a rss feed. my problem is. I want to build a grid using html and javascript with sencha and nimblekit but how can I use the information of that array?, remember that the array is built purely in xcode. or maybe if there is another method that i can use. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

goto https://github.com/pixelspring/NKBlueprint-Obj-C-Mix-Edition
download the project.

Look at the Objective C class listFilesInDocumentsFolder, 
it does allocate an array and pass it to the javascript worldÄ